# How to output watir-webdriver/firefox logs for each test?

Tags: ruby, firefox, cucumber, watir-webdriver

My tests run using ruby/watir-webdriver/cucumber/firefox. If possible I would like to save the browser and webdriver logs if those are available. It looks like there is loggingPrefs for webdriver + firefox but not really sure how to use that.

Comment: Is there something specific in the logs you are looking for? I know of one log that gets generated, but not sure if it is the one you are looking for.

Comment: When clicking on a submit button on a form I am redirected to another page. However on that next page it will never finish loading. It will go into a refresh loop before the page is complete. I want to see what if anything is happening during that time. In the browser console I see it making a couple calls then it reloads. I figured out the profile.log_file = 'mylog.txt' so I will try with that for now.